# fetch specific record from db when related date from datepicker is selected, show that value in input box

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

my code is for booking one day picnic, where i set value for each date and save it to db. now i want to select a date from datepicker and te related value should be reflected in input box from db. every time i select date the value should be changed as per saved in db.

here is my code

//php code

```
$search_num = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from newroom where datepicker = '$datepicker'");
$r = mysqli_fetch_array($search_num,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$rate = $r['rate'];
```

//jquery code

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: "+2d", dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $('#bookings').attr('value',rate);              
    }
});
```

here i am getting only last record that i saved in db but i want every time it should change the value as per date selected.

Comment: two things:- 1:- show your full code(like how you are sending date value to php code). 2:- what format is save in table for date `'dd-mm-yy'` or something else?

Comment: You can call ajax on `onSelect:function(){}` and pass the selected value from datepicker. and on ajax page you can write the query and get output